# Save multiple pictures with Blazor WASM

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0, asp.net-blazor

I would like to download multiple files with Blazor webassembly I found this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0

that shows how to download one file.

Does someone knows a solution that doesn't prompt the user for each files so I can download a full gallery of images?

Comment: Do you mean the prompt to ask where to save files? This is a browser specific setting controlled by the user.

Comment: @JesseGood yes when you have 100+ files to save it starts to be a pain to have to do multiple clicks for each

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot control this through the browser. This is why [extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-mass-downloader/abdkkegmcbiomijcbdaodaflgehfffed) are made for these types of problems.

Comment: There is an upcoming [Filesystem API](https://caniuse.com/filesystem) that might suit your needs...